# Multivariate stationarity/cointegration test

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, stationarity, cointegration, augmented-dickey-fuller

Am I right to say that for multivariate time series, we can't use normal stationary test like Dickey–Fuller test and we need to use cointegration Test like Johansen? Or this is not true in general?

Comment: Depends on what hypothesis you wish to test. E.g. Dickey-Fuller tests for a unit root, which is not strictly the same as lack of stationarity in general (it is hard to test presence of stationarity comprehensively).